# Vuetify flex wrapping to content and not row?

Tags: flexbox, vuetify.js

I am trying to use the [Vuetify Flex CSS Helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex) to create cards with varying heights. The cards can wrap when there is no more space. However, I would like the wrapping to be more intelligent. Right now they wrap to the bottom of the previous "row", but is there a way to get them to wrap to content with the highest bottom to minimize the amount of space is allocated for the entire component? Here is some sample code:

```
<v-card class="d-flex flex-wrap" color="grey lighten-2" flat tile>
  <v-card class="align-self-start" outlined tile>
    ...
  </v-card>
  <v-card class="align-self-start" outlined tile>
    ...
  </v-card>
  ...
</v-card>
```

[Here is a full CodePen example](https://codepen.io/CodeVirtue/pen/abzQQKx?editors=1000). In it you will see when the last card wraps, it goes to be under the first card. But there is a lot of vertical space between the first card and the last card now. I would like to remove that vertical space. Is this possible?

[image: Card wrapped to bottom of previous row]

Thanks